# Django use string as a query object attribute

Tags: django

I want to access query using `string` attribute

```
>>> colObj = College.objects.get(id=1)
>>> name = "collegeName"
```

Now  I want college name using object attribute as a `string`.

**Excepted Output:**

```
>>> colName = colObj.name
>>> colname
>>> 'abc'
```

Comment: Can you reword your question so it makes a little more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
colObj = College.objects.get(id=1)
name = "collegeName"
colName = getattr(colObj, name)
```